# How many Perks can you start a run with?

Tags: one-way-heroics

I was able to choose 4 perks before starting an adventure. But after beating the game once I can now pick 5 perks. I am not sure if that was the actual way I earned the extra slot but it was when I noticed. What is the maximum number of perks I will be able to start an adventure with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've 100%'ed the game, and my max is 5.  [Others on the Steam forums](http://steamcommunity.com/app/266210/discussions/0/540734792412590616/) seem to agree this is the maximum number there are.

I believe the 2 extra slots are unlocked by the achievements "2 Legit 2 Quit" and "I Need More Power!!!" which require that you get to 100km and 300km 3 times.